# Number of Threads in Kernel

Tags: kernel, thread

How can I get the number of threads in the kernel at specific sampling rate? I need to measure the utilization of the system directly by myself.

Comment: Use `top` and switch the view with `H`, that will show you the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ps -eL|wc -l
```

gives total number of lwp/thread count at any point of time

Answer (score 2):

Even though, @VenkatC's answer is correct, more optimal would be to get info from `/proc/loadavg` file:

```
awk '{split($4,a,"/");print a[2]}' /proc/loadavg
```